# Reasking a question with modified conditions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I asked a question about the mounting of an electronic part ([this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217339/pin-mounts-horizontal-pin-rows)). Now my requirements for the mounting changed a bit, but the device stayed the same. Should I change the question itself, or just open a new question with a link to the old one?

Comment: You might want to tell more about the changed requirements. Do they really require a different answer? Changing the question is usually a bad idea since it renders the answers already given useless at best, wrong and misleading at worst.

Comment: I stated that the device can be fixed with bent legs, but now its legs should stay horizontal, with minimal changes on the device. Nevertheless it is ok now to fix it permanently.